# Keyboard shortcuts with square brackets (swiss keyboard)

Tags: keyboard

IntelliJ has some keyboard shortcuts that use square brackets. On my swiss keyboard I type square brackets with <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> and <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>.

IntelliJ now for example has the keyboard shortcut: <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>
I am unable to use that keyboard shortcut. I tried it by pressing <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>.

How do I do that?

Comment: Have you tried Cmd + the two keys to the right of P? Quite often these commands keep their position but change character, & that's where they are on English keyboards.

Comment: Griezi und willkommen bei Ask Different :-) The keys Tetsujin refers to are "ü" (u umlaut) and "¨" (umlaut). Could you try it and report back?

Comment: oops - Shift/Cmd, not plain Cmd. In case it may be relevant, the characters accessed by shift [ and ] are curly brackets { and }.

Comment: Grüezi :) And thanks for your support. I tried it, but it's not working.

But I found out that the same command is also mapped to the shortcut ctrl+left. Initially it was not working because it was overridden by a system shortcut. But now that I disabled the system shortcut it works.

I can live with that. I think the square bracket shortcuts are unusable on my keyboard.